# Add custom field into header in STOMP message

Tags: java, spring, stomp

I want to add version: 1.1 into STOMP message header like that:

```
destination:/cora/1234/panelapp/code/response
content-type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
subscription:sub-0
message-id:bdyqehdj-5
content-length:492
**Version: 1.2**
```

```
@Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
        StompHeaderAccessor sha = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
        StompCommand command = sha.getCommand();
        sha.setHeader(sha.STOMP_MESSAGE_HEADER, "1.2");
        sha.setVersion("1.2");
        sha.addNativeHeader(sha.STOMP_MESSAGE_HEADER, "1.2");
        return message;
}
```

But in postSend method I cannot find the version info in the headers. How can I get the version info into PostSend method which is set from preSend method in ChannelInterceptorAdapter.

---

**Update**:

```
@Override public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) { 
 return MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message).setHeader("Version","1.‌​2").build(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can set the headers as key/value pairs:

```
  MutableMessageBuilder.fromMessage(message)
            .setHeader("key","value")
            .build();
```

Comment: I have tried with your mentioned way but I got the below exception: 
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: MessageHeaders is immutable

Comment: @Amit can you try like above

Comment: I found below from getMessageHeader() in PostSend method: 
getMessageHeaders: {simpMessageType=MESSAGE, nativeHeaders={destination=[/cora/1234/panelapp/code/response], content-type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}, simpSubscriptionId=sub-0, conversionHint=method 'checkPin' parameter -1, contentType=application/json;charset=UTF-8, simpSessionId=hlb2dg5z, simpDestination=/cora/1234/panelapp/code/response} .      But not found key in the header info

Comment: But you are sending back the same message not forming the message after doing the changes with sha reference?. Am I missing something here

Comment: `@Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
     MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message).setHeader("Version","1.2").build();
     StompHeaderAccessor sha = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
        StompCommand command = sha.getCommand();
        return message;
    }`

`   StompHeaderAccessor sha = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
        logger.info("+sha.getMessageHeaders().toString());`